# Is it more efficient to pass large parcelable or pass id and query db?

Tags: android, mysql

Just like it says on the tin. I have a decent sized object, consisting of about 20 variables, some of which are themselves android objects (Calendar, Uri). An arbitrary number of these objects are stored in a database.

I need to pass an individual object by intent to a broadcast receiver. When I create the intent I already have the entire object as a local variable and would not be querying the database. Is it more efficient to pass the entire object as a parcel, or to pass the database id and pull the object from the db in my onReceive method?

I suspect the former, but until yesterday I was doing the latter because I was too lazy to implement parcelable. I did, but now I'm second guessing myself.

P.S. I'm no CS major. In this case I define most efficient to mean least impact on user experience.

Comment: "I need to pass an individual object by intent to a broadcast receiver" -- why are you using a `BroadcastReceiver`? Is it tied to some `PendingIntent`?

Comment: Yes, I should have said PendingIntent. It's for an alarm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the object in question is small (under 1MB), then going the `Parcelable` route should be more efficient. Basically, you avoid the disk I/O (and the accompanying complexity of trying to do that on a background thread when triggered by a broadcast).

Comment: Is there an easy way to estimate object size from the variables it contains?

Comment: @TBridges42: If it doesn't hold a `Bitmap`, `Cursor`, or text you got from teh Interwebs, you're probably OK. :-) The 1MB thing is a design-time consideration: if there's a remote chance that it might happen, don't go the `Parcelable` route, as you crash at runtime if your `Intent` (with its extras) exceeds 1MB. In those cases, pass the ID, but consider caching the POJOs, so that if the process happens to still be around by the time the broadcast occurs, you can just grab the POJO out of the cache, but you have the ID as a fallback mechanism.